# Strip numbers - leave only the name in sql impala

Tags: sql, cloudera, impala

I have a list of org_names, such as

```
12345678 - West Highland
87654321 - (Vacant) 
12348765 - (Closed)   etc
```

What I want to be left with is only the valid names - in this case West Highland

I striped everything but the numbers with:

```
SELECT substr(org_name,1,locate(' ',org_name)) as position_num
FROM old;
```

But how do you do it if I want to only keep the name and name it : name?
Is three a way to get rid of names like

```
- (Vacant) 
- (Closed) 

 = empty
```

Comment: You need to clarify how to distinguish between valid and invalid names.

Comment: - (Vacant) 
- (Closed)  are not names

Comment: Oh really, that's not helpful. What about UNMANAGED, is that a name for instance? Again you need to clarify the logic to distinguish between valid names and the bad strings (whatever you want to call them).

Comment: Hi there are position numbers with a - between the number and the first surname If the position is closed, there is no name associated to the position number anymore. the number remains, but the position is then either -(vacant) or - (closed)

Comment: it looks like                                                                                                                      12233445 - David Vincent                                                                                         56675678 - (Vacant)                                                                                          34454556 - Ben Smith                                                                                                                   89786756 - (Closed)

Comment: There are no 'names" = UNMANAGED

Comment: Do you want the leading space hyphen space included, or for the returned string to start with the first character of the name? Do you want (Vacant) and (Closed) to return empty string, or NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most efficient way

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN locate('(Closed)', org_name) THEN split_part(org_name, '-', 1)
    CASE WHEN locate('(Vacant)', org_name) THEN split_part(org_name, '-', 1)
    ELSE org_name
    END
FROM old
```

This might also work but I am a little unsure about the regular expression syntax

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN regex_like(org_name, '(\\(Closed\\)|\\(Vacant\\))') THEN split_part(org_name, '-', 1)
    ELSE org_name
    END
FROM old
```

Comment: does not work - outcome: 22000 - UNMANAGED 22001 - UNMANAGED 22002- UNMANAGED ETC

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right I can advise you to use power of regular expressions to select/modify/delete what you need.

Example:

```
SELECT name
FROM table
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (name, '^A(*)');
```

This REGEXP_LIKE example will return a name which starts with 'A'.